# Showing the location which I get from phonegap geolocation

Tags: html, google-maps, cordova

I am building an app using PhoneGap Build. In my application I'm getting the current location and I want to show it as a Google Map inside my page. I tried to show the map as an image but then I decided to have a Google Map.

Is there any way to show the google map in my page?

Comment: Set the lat, lng variables and i suggest Using Gmaps Js plugging to display the map as its very easy -- http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the GoogleMap you don't have to use the geolocation plugin. If you open www.maps.google.com in the InAppBrowser (Plugin) it automatically ask you for your position.

If you want to display an inline GoogleMap with the Cords from the geolocation Plugin you have to save the cords and after that you may be able to display them on the google map.

But i would realise this with the inappbrowser plugin.

cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser and after that you can set a link like

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.maps.google.de/', '_blank', 'location=no')"> 
     <img alt="" src="img/start/btncard.png" width="80" height="58" class="foo_nav">
</a>
```

so if you want to know something about the options (location=no stands for: no location bar for example) you can read the documentation about this Plugin over here: [InAppBrowser-Plugin Cordova Docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md)

Just found that [Google Maps + Geolocation-Plugin without inAppBrowser](http://www.devx.com/wireless/implement-google-maps-api-on-phonegap-using-the-device-api.html) hope that will help you!

Comment: I see that innappbrowser opens a new window in the app. I would rather not leave my app and do the job inside. Therefore I want to display an inline GoogleMap with the coords from geolocation.

Comment: Look at my edit. I just found sth. that may help you :)